# Android: Focus behavior

Tags: android, user-interface, focus

I have a parent gridview with several subviews in the grid. Some of these views are empty and I would not like the focus (via keypad) to go on them. I tried setFocusable(false) for these but that didnt work. I also tried setClickable(false) and setEnabled(false), still all the views are getting the focus.

Then I decided to try removing focus from the parent GridView - that worked but now using setFocusable(true) on child views that I want to have focus doesn't work. It seems the child views are only listening to their parent behavior and not their own.
Hw can I resolve this issue ? Please help.

Comment: Which view you want to setFocusable(false)??

Comment: Some blank views in my GridView

Comment: use that setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

Comment: That doesnt work - only the content of the blank view is hidden (which is empty anyway) - focus still goes on empty grids

Comment: Put the code into question